# Is it possible to do your own efficient descriptive statistics function? - R

Tags: r

Usually, I find myself using a few summary functions or making my own computations to get some additional initial information from the data. For example, I wanted to see the count and percentage per variable given a limit of distinct values:

```
table_transposed <- function(vector){

    merge(as.data.frame(table(vector, dnn="values")),
          as.data.frame(round(prop.table(table(vector, dnn="values")),2)), 
          by="values", 
          all.x=TRUE) %>% 
    data.table::transpose(keep.names = "values",
                          make.names = names(.)[1]) %T>%
    {.[,c("values")] <- c("Count", "Percentage")}
    }
table_transposed_filter <- function(dataframe, max_number_categories) {
    (lapply(dataframe, function(x) NROW(unique(x))) <= max_number_categories) %>% 
            as.vector() %>% 
            {dataframe[,.]} %>% 
            lapply(table_transposed)
            }
```

So, you give the dataframe and the threshold of distinct values per variable.

```
table_transposed_filter(mtcars, 10)
```

However, it's SUPER slow (maybe because of using `merge()` instead of `left_join()` from `dplyr`). Now, I'm trying to figure an efficient, fast, and simple way to do a combination of `psych::describe()`, `Hmisc::describe()`, other, and my own, for numeric and categorical variables (one descriptive function for each one). Something like (for numerical):

| Variable | dtype | mean | mode | variance | skew | percentile 25 | ...

If I create this table with mainly with `sapply()` for example, is it better (more efficient, faster, simpler code) than actually learning to create a r-package and developing in there?

PS: I thought to put this question in StackMetaExchange or Crossvalidation, but none of them seem to fit it.

Comment: If you are worried about speed, spend some time [profiling your code](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-measure.html) to see what's actually taking a long time. When asking a question here you should include data that makes the problem clear. Exactly how slow is too slow for you? Include specific benchmarks that must be met.

Comment: re: your PS - yes, Stack Overflow is the right place for the question, you just need to address MrFlick's points. The question is about programming, making it squarely on-topic here. Meta Stack Overflow is for questions about using Stack Overflow. Cross Validated is for statistics questions.

Comment: A couple inefficiencies do jump out: (a) `table_transpose` uses `table(vector, dnn = "values")` twice - it would be more efficient to do it once, save it as a variable, and use it twice. I also don't think `merge` is needed at all - `table` and `prop.table` are in the same order. And I'm pretty confused by the `NROW(unique(x))) <= max_number_categories)` being piped in... `table_transposed` is already returning a result with a dimension of the number of unique categories, inefficient to calculate it again.

Comment: Ah - I missed a set of parentheses, and now I see the `NROW(unique())` was pre-filtering, which is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat faster version. It's about 2x faster on small data (like `mtcars`), but the difference narrows on *litte bit* on larger data.

This makes sense as the most expensive operation you do is `table` - your version does it twice, my version does it once. I didn't profile the code, but my guess is `table` is the bottleneck by more than one order of magnitude on any sizeable data, so it's a waste to try to optimize any other parts of the code.

```
t_transp = function(x, digits = 2) {
  tab = table(x)
  prop_tab = prop.table(tab)
  df = data.frame(values = c("Count", "Percentage"))
  df = cbind(df, rbind(tab, round(prop_tab, digits = digits)))
  row.names(df) = NULL
  df
}

t_transp_filter = function(data, n_max, ...) {
  lapply(Filter(function(x) NROW(unique(x)) <= n_max, data), t_transp, ...)
}
```

Benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  gregor = t_transp_filter(mtcars, n_max = 4),
  OP = table_transposed_filter(mtcars, 4),
  times = 20
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
#  gregor 1.6483 1.7093 2.253425 1.74765 1.84680 7.5394    20  a 
#      OP 5.6988 5.7627 6.316295 6.08545 6.57965 8.1048    20   b

set.seed(47)
df = as.data.frame(matrix(
  c(sample(letters[1:5], size = 1e5 * 20, replace = T))
  , ncol = 20))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  gregor = t_transp_filter(df, n_max = 5),
  OP = table_transposed_filter(df, 5),
  times = 20
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#  gregor  59.5466  59.95545  63.6825  61.14075  67.2167  75.4270    20  a 
#      OP 110.3265 117.35585 123.8782 118.91005 133.7795 149.0651    20   b
```